# Changing elements in SVG using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, svg

I have this:

```
<button type="button" id="btn" value="Release">Click Here!</button>     
...

<body>
<object data="books.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svg" width="1300" height="700"></object>
</body>

<script>
var a = document.getElementById("svg");
var svgDoc

a.addEventListener("load", function() {
     svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
}, false);

$(window).load(function() {
    console.log($(svgDoc).find("#book1").attr("fill"))
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        console.log("You are here")
        $(svgDoc).find("#book1").attr("fill","#000000")
    })
})
```

`$(window).load(function() {` works, but

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
```

... doesn't. Why is that?

Edit: Added more code

Edit #2: Got it to work. Followed Robert Longson's suggestion and changed this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {....})
```

to this:

```
a.addEventListener("load", function() {...}, false);
```

JQuery:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {...}
```

Comment: what happens when you do `console.log($(svgDoc).find("#book1").attr("fill"))` after setting the `fill` attribute ?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Try adding the `;` to the end of the `click` function as well as the `$(document).ready`?

Comment: No errors. On the console it prints out: #BDCDD1

Comment: @ckpepper02 Didn't work

Comment: Just to confirm, are you implementing jQuery somewhere on your page?

Comment: Yes, the $(window).load(function() wouldn't work otherwise, right?

Comment: What if you change `.attr("fill","#000000")` to `.attr("style","fill:#000000")`

Comment: The code doesn't even print "You are here" to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready();
```

Will fire as soon as the web browser runs after the parser is done with the DOM for that page, but before all the embedded objects are initialised. This is useful if you want to execute JavaScript as soon as possible, but it's not what you want in your case. I imagine it is implemented off the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event as that matches the [ready() description](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

You need the UA to have loaded the `<object>` contents in order to manipulate it. You can attach to the `<object>` element onload event or as you are doing to the page onload.

Comment: I need to be able to continually use the function, not just on load.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you can access and modify the `<object>` contents at any point after the load event has fired.

Comment: Why does '$(document).ready(function() { $("#btn").click(function() {...' not work then? I click the button after I see the svg file displayed.

Comment: What does books.svg look like?

Comment: No, you've helpfully added stuff to the question in case anyone else runs across this so everyone's good now.